# Как работать с конкурирующими запросами в Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть таблица постов, есть привязанная таблица оценок со значениями от 1 до 5. Необходима возможность делать выборку и сортировку исходя из средней оценки поста. Для ускорения работы запросов я добавил в посты колонку avg_rating, чтобы не высчитывать каждый раз на ходу средствами sql, в которую заношу среднее значение по всем оценкам, посредством коллбэка after_save в модели оценок. Само значение высчитывается средствами sql. Возможны ли проблемы с расчетом этого среднего значения при такой схеме, когда множество юзеров одновременно выставляют свои оценки?

Comment: @D-side , я предполагал сделать связанную с постами таблицу оценок, с уникальностью по id поста и юзера, чтобы один юзер мог оставить только одну оценку посту. Рассчет среднего значения организовать в коллбэке after_save модели оценок.

Comment: @D-side , так я делал ранее и при проверке модератором проблем не предвижу. Я же хочу понять как такое сделать в случае обычного ресурса, где модератор для оценок не требуется.

Comment: изменил вопрос, убрал сбивающие с толку моменты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Да, вполне себе возможны.** Типичные уровни изоляции (read committed) видят только уже закоммиченные данные. До коммита текущей транзакции они могут измениться, из-за чего среднее посчитается из неполных данных и да, может не учесть некоторые оценки.

Ситуацию можно исправить, обновляя среднее в `after_commit` (не `_save`!), когда транзакция завершилась и записалась (закоммитилась). Так, даже если в момент обновления среднего параллельно шла транзакция с добавлением новой оценки, после её коммита обновление будет сделано повторно и среднее снова станет правильным. То есть, в этом случае реальное среднее значение может немножко опережать записанное: меньше чем на длительность транзакции. На практике большего обычно и не нужно.

---

Если хотите устранить даже этот эффект, потребуется что-нибудь тяжёлое вроде максимального уровня изоляции транзакций, `SERIALIZABLE`, транзакцию в котором можно запустить явно [методом `transaction` у класса модели](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-transaction).

Вышеописанная проблема — разновидность того, что [в документации PostgreSQL называют "аномалия сериализации"](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/10/transaction-iso). Допустим в некоторый заданный момент времени мы имеем две *идущие* (незакоммиченные) транзакции:

- Одна вставила новую оценку 1 и записала новое среднее X, не учтя оценку 2.
- Другая вставила новую оценку 2 и записала новое среднее Y, не учтя оценку 1.

Cреднее значение, учитывающее **сразу 1 и 2** не вычислено **ни одной из транзакций**, поэтому фиксация их в любом порядке приведёт базу в несогласованное состояние. В этой ситуации СУБД применит какую-то **одну** транзакцию, а остальные **отменит**, и их потребуется **повторить**. Скорее всего, применится первая из них, что попробует закоммититься, и именно в этот момент транзакции, использующие устаревшие результаты чтения, будут отменены. В этом примере, если никакие новые транзакции не возникнут, одна из транзакций отменится, при повторном запуске посчитает *правильное* среднее и сохранит его.

Это может замедлить работу, если у вас такие ситуации будут происходить ну очень часто, и тем хуже, чем больше параллелизм.

Делает ли AR из Rails повтор самостоятельно, мне неизвестно, но если вам это важно, на это должны быть тесты. Имея их, можно быстро проверить разные реализации.